# When I install the Flutter and Dart plugins in Android Studio, does that handle downloading their SDK's?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I did a Windows reset and am reinstalling everything for my Flutter app. I decided to delete my flutter and dart sdks because I remembered that you can install the flutter and dart plugins from Android Studio, so I figured that my directories would be cleaner if I do it this way. But after installing both plugins, I get a blue bar at the top of my editor in Android Studio that says Dart SDK is not configured. When I open Dart settings, I enable the dart checkbox but then it asks me to specify a path to the Dart SDK. So now I'm thinking that downloading the plugins in Android Studio is NOT the same as downloading the actual SDKs themselves...

Answer (score 1):

As far as i have known the relevant `SDKs` will be downloaded for you when you install the `Flutter` and `Dart` plugins in Android Studio, but they might not be placed in the default location on your PC.

In your scenario, the plugins are asking you to manually provide the path to the `Dart SDK` because you removed your `Flutter` and `Dart SDKs`. The Dart SDK must be downloaded separately, and the settings must include the path to it.

Normally `Android Studio` will prompt you to install any necessary Flutter development-related missing components, such as the `Flutter` SDK, when you start a new `Flutter` project. The plugins will automatically download and install these parts for you, but if the SDK is not already set up in the default place on your machine, you might need to specify the path to it.

Comment: Ok so if I let Android Studio download the flutter SDK for me, where would it put it?

Comment: it depends on the directory you chose during installation. Normally on Windows, the Flutter SDK is installed by default in the `C:\src\flutter `directory. You can aswell check `File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Flutter`